# Unable to read from request body

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to send an email where the values are dependent on the values from the form in the Frontend, but they are always null.

**Controller**

```
    @PostMapping("/send")
    public void sendEmail(Contact contact) throws MessagingException {
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setTo("test@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setSubject(contact.getSubject()); //This is always null
        mailMessage.setFrom("arasto.developer@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setText("To confirm ationToken()););");
        emailSenderService.sendEmail(mailMessage);
    }
```

**Entity**

```
public class Contact {

    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String subject;
    private String content;

    public Contact() { }

    //...getters & setters
```

**My Post**, This gives me `200 OK`
[image]

**Result** Subject not being displayed.
[image]

Any suggestions of where i've gone wrong and how i could correct this are much appreciated.

Comment: can you try adding `@RequestBody` in your parameter? `public void sendEmail(@RequestBody Contact contact)`. I think your api cannot read your request because of that.

Comment: have you debugged and verified that the original value which you map to your message is not null?

Comment: wow this actually solved the issue. Such a miss, but thank you for helping me out.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend method parameter with `@RequestBody` annotation as below:

> public void sendEmail(@RequestBody Contact contact) throws MessagingException {